# jQuery selector isn't triggering a click event on my image icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an assortment of divs that each have an identical dropdown menu. When my active element is on one of the image icons (chevron down) I'm trying to mimic a click event. The only problem is that when the function fires off, it does nothing?

HTML:

```
<div class="appExperience small-tile">
<div class="blue-bar">
<h2 class="tile-header">APPLICATION EXPERIENCE</h2>
<span class="dropdown hidden-xs">
<i class="tcm-chevron glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down expand-icon dropdown-toggle"
   role="button"
   aria-labledby="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"
   ng-src="{{dropdown_appExperience}}"
   data-toggle="dropdown"
   tabindex="0"
   alt="Expand Application Experience Summary Dropdown Menu"></i>
<ul class="dropdown-menu appExperience tileContextMenu">
    <li>
   List Item 1
    </li>
    <li>
   List Item 2
    </li>
     ...
```

What i've tried:

```
$(window).on("keydown", function() {

            console.log(document.activeElement);
            console.log($(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0]);

                if (document.activeElement === $(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0])  {

                            console.log("activeElement is recognized!")   

                            $(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0].focus( function() {
                                $( this ).trigger("click"); 
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: So how are you making that element to be the active Element? Does it log the _activeElement is recognized!_?

Comment: By simply tabbing through the dom until it's selected

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting any errors in your console? `$(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0].focus()` is not an event handler since the `[0]` returns an `HTMLElement` object, whose `focus` member is a function that makes the element in question receive focus...

Answer (score 1):

You should know that

```
$(window).on("keydown", function() { … });
```

will register a handler that will fire on *every single* keyboard action on your entire page. If you want to limit this to <kbd>TAB</kbd>, consider checking [`event.keyCode === 9`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.keyCode) or better [`event.key === 'Tab'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key).

---

The following code has few issues:

```
if (document.activeElement === $(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0]) {
   console.log("activeElement is recognized!")   
    $(".glyphicon-chevron-down")[0].focus(function() {
      $( this ).trigger("click"); 
    });
  }
});
```

1. as @Mike McCaughan already pointed out in the comment, `$(selector)[0]` will give you an `HTMLElement`, so you're calling [HTMLElement.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus), and not [jQuery.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
2. If registering the `focus` event handler was successful, you'd end up with a bunch of handlers being registered. Because you only add listeners, but never remove them.
3. This code checks if `.glyphicon-chevron-down` is the activeElemnt and if that's the case, it attempts to add a `focus` event listener. This is pointless, because at this point the element already has focus - that's why it's the activeElement.

---

What is your goal with "mimicing a click event"?

Answer (score 0):

Th problem is that you're triggering the click event inside the focus event... which get's hooked on on every keydown events.  In fact, you only need to listen to the `keydown` event, then trigger the click event if the acttive element is your chevron:

```
$(window).on("keydown", function() {
    var chevron = $(".glyphicon-chevron-down");
    if (document.activeElement === chevron[0]) {
        chevron.trigger("click"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: There is a improper parenthesis at ending of line 2 and trigger is JQuery function that means chevron should be wrapped by $.